# Is collision-ignorance symmetric?

Tags: dota-2

If I'm playing Spectre, Centaur Warrunner, or various other heroes, I can ignore collision on all units, so if I right-click on the other side of a unit then I'll just breeze through to the other side. Will that also mean that creeps and heroes will path through me, or will their usual pathing rules still apply?

Comment: Why not just test this by standing in front of your own creeps and asking someone to walk through you at the beginning of a game?

Comment: I'm away from my main gaming computer for a couple of days, so I can't really test it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have free pathing / phase / whatever, the creeps will run through you.